# Re-run last failed test in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

You may use `--stop-on-failure` flag to break the unit testing when one of the tests fails.

Is there any way quick way to tell PHPUnit to re-run this failed test, instead providing the full path manually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the `--filter` cli option. You can find an example in the [**`organisation docs`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html) and in the [**`CLI Docs`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/textui.html).

> --filter
>
> Only runs tests whose name matches the given pattern. The pattern can be either the name of a single test or a regular expression that matches multiple test names.

Assume your run `phpunit Tests/` and `Tests/Stuff/ThatOneTestClassAgain::testThisWorks` fails:

your options are:

`phpunit --filter ThatOneTestClassAgain`

and

`phpunit --filter testThisWorks`

or most other strings that somehow make sense

Comment: If you have a phpunit.xml setup for your tests, I created a short bash script that will use phpunit logging of your last test-run to populate this --filter with classes that contained failed tests. Simply read the comments on top of this [gist](https://gist.github.com/bksunday/6922149#file-test-run-failed).

Comment: links are no longer valid

Answer (score 36):

[Since PHPUnit 7.3](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/3147), you can cache the results of your tests, then order your tests by defects.

In phpunit.xml, enable `cacheResults`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit cacheResult="true"
         ...>
```

If you don't want to edit your phpunit.xml, you could also run your tests with the `--cache-result` flag.

When caching results, PHPUnit will create a `.phpunit.result.cache` file after running tests. Make sure to add this file to your global gitignore file.

You can run your tests like this to run previously failed tests first:

```
phpunit --order-by=defects --stop-on-failure
```

Comment: cacheResult is true by default in PHPUnit 9.*

Comment: Will this stop after all failed tests succeed? This will only give you "fast feedback" on whatever failed in the last run. But it will still run all the tests in the end if you fixed everything, no?

Answer (score 2):

The way I've found to implement it is fairly easy, but requires logging to be implemented. You setup phpunit to log to a json file. Then you alter the phpunit command to something similar to:

```
cd /home/vagrant/tests && php -d auto_prepend_file=./tests-prepend.php /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

What this does is auto_prepend a php file before the execution of phpunit. This way we can capture $argsv and supply the required filter command automatically to phpunit.

**tests-prepend.php**
(make sure to amend the file pathway of the json log)

```
<?php

global $argv, $argc;
if(empty($argv) === false) {
    // are we re-running?
    $has_rerun = false;
    foreach ($argv as $key => $value) {
        if($value === '--rerun-failures') {
            $has_rerun = true;
            unset($argv[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
    if($has_rerun === true) {
        // validate the path exists and if so then capture the json data.
        $path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../logs/report.json');
        if(is_file($path) === true) {
            // special consideration taken here as phpunit does not store the report as a json array.
            $data = json_decode('['.str_replace('}{'.PHP_EOL, '},{'.PHP_EOL, file_get_contents($path).']'), true);
            $failed = array();
            // capture the failures as well as errors but taking care not to capture skipped tests.
            foreach ($data as $event) {
                if($event['event'] === 'test') {
                    if($event['status'] === 'fail') {
                        $failed[] = array($event['test'], 'failed');
                    }
                    elseif($event['status'] === 'error' && $event['trace'][0]['function'] !== 'markTestIncomplete') {
                        $failed[] = array($event['test'], 'error\'d');
                    }
                }
            }
            if(empty($failed) === true) {
                echo 'There are no failed tests to re-run.'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
                exit;
            }
            else{
                echo '--------------------------------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
                echo 'Re-running the following tests: '.PHP_EOL;
                foreach ($failed as $key => $test_data) {
                    echo ' - '.$test_data[0].' ('.$test_data[1].')'.PHP_EOL;
                    // important to escapre the namespace backslashes.
                    $failed[$key] = addslashes($test_data[0]);
                }
                echo '--------------------------------------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
            }
            $argv[] = '--filter';
            $argv[] = '/('.implode('|', $failed).')/';
            // important to update the globals in every location.
            $_SERVER['argv'] = $GLOBALS['_SERVER']['argv'] = $GLOBALS['argv'] = $argv = array_values($argv);
            $_SERVER['argc'] = $GLOBALS['_SERVER']['argc'] = $GLOBALS['argc'] = $argc = count($argv);
        }
        else{
            echo 'The last run report log at '.$path.' does not exist so it is not possible to re-run the failed tests. Please re-run the test suite without the --rerun-failures command.'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```