# Repeat failed test with phpunit

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

When I using PHPUnit, some tests are failed, I want to repeat unit testing for failed tests and not for passed tests. Is there a way to do that!?

I can filter tests, but I want to automatically do that.

Thanks

---

For some one else with problem like my problem, following links is useful ([Re-run last failed test in PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119886/re-run-last-failed-test-in-phpunit?rq=1))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHPUnit do not keep track of failed and passed tests. The response is on the fly. The idea of having something like that can kill all the automated test concept. Think about it. You are automating your tests because you wanna be warned when some change break your code. But you only know if something broke your code when you run the automated test. There is no guarantee that the fix you made for one testcase, will not break another testcase.

PHPUnit help you to make sure your code works even when you fixed what was causing some testcase to fail.

Comment: You are right, PHPUnit help me to make sure the codes are work fine after any chagnes.

Comment: I get your point and you are correct, however you are failing to see that many tests are run manually. Having an additional argument to keep track of failed tests for text correction purposes is actually a valid use case especially when your tests suite has 10's of 1000's of tests.