# How to run PHPUnit from where it failed from previous try

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Assume we have 500 unit tests and running all of them by:

```
php ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c ./phpunit.xml
```

and 450 tests passed but failed at unit-test 451.

Now I fixed the uni-test 451 and don't want to re-run 450 tests again and just want to continue testing from 451 to the the end.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: What if your changes make one of the earlier test fail now?

Comment: Totally agreed with @NigelRen but answer to your question could be checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095051/how-to-run-single-test-method-with-phpunit).

Comment: You can check this link maybe you may help
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119886/re-run-last-failed-test-in-phpunit)

Comment: I do use PHPStorm, so running only failed tests is very easy, just clicking on a specific icon, but doing that using the CLI, I think it uses `--filter`. But still, you should ALWAYS run all the tests (at least related to the change, makes no sense to run a job test that is never run on a controller you are testing, but still), all tests should be run locally

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-run last failed test in PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119886/re-run-last-failed-test-in-phpunit)